# How to refresh a page once it's opened from a previous link?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a table with live data in it (meaning it is stored on the server and people who has access can view the data in their machine as well). I have a Create data page and View data page that contains the table. Once I have finished creating a new data and click a link going to the View page. The data should be there already.

I have tried the location.load() internal script in the View.html page that is triggered by the attribute onLoad="" but it's not working. However, when I create a button that has a function to refresh, it does work but I want it to be an auto refresh.

Comment: With almost no info (at time of comment) to go on: If using PHP on the backend, you could use `session` to propagate the data, else if using JS through AJAX, you could use JSON in localStorage. Questions should really be accompanied by examples of what you've already tried, and some indication of your current code.

Comment: im only using js though. I tried the <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30"> but it's time based

Answer (score 0):

To make it easy and simple, use location.reload(). You can also use location.reload(true) if you want to grab something from the server.

Comment: search about location.reload() first .

Comment: I want to put it in the html page. but this didn't work still

<div onLoad="location.reload(true)">

</div>

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use an jQuery Ajax call to make call to your backend API and fetch data, which you can add to your html table. This process you can handle in page/document ready or load events. I don't think you need to reload the page just to achieve this.

If you are working with AngularJs SPA (mentioning this as you added the tag), these two HTMLs/Pages can be rendered into the same layout based on the route and follow the above mentioned approach (using $http.get of Angular) to get view data  and bind it to the respective view. As it is SPA, no concept of page reload.